# Ctrl-Z on an SSH session

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, terminal

When I SSH into another system and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, I expected the SSH client to go into background.  However, it's the remote process that does that.  Where does the magic happen?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The SSH client disables special key handling (`stty -icanon -isig` options) for the local tty, so when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, the client just reads the raw byte `0x1A` and forwards it to the server.

OpenSSH supports a special command to suspend the client – <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>~</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: At begining of line type `~?` to get a full list of escape codes. You can change the escape character using -e when you start ssh. (this applies to openssh, used on most Gnu systems.)

Comment: I expected the local ssh client to be suspended, not the process on the remote machine. Is there a reason why the ordinary `Ctrl-Z` is modified instead of a new `~ Ctrl-Z` being added for stopping the remote process?